# htaccess redirect for multilanguage website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I needed to remove the language slug from my urls via htaccess:
(ENGLISH) https://www.mywebsite.it/en/art/architecture/
(ITALIAN) https://www.mywebsite.it/it/arte/architettura/

I've found this code into stack:
RedirectMatch 301 /it/(.*) /$1
and it worked. The problem is that I have a multilanguage website, and when I do the same thing for the english language adding:
RedirectMatch 301 /en/(.*) /$1
when I click on the logo, instead of going to the english home it goes to the italian one. How I can fix this avoiding the removal of the /en/ slug from the english homepage? Thanks a lot.

Comment: hi salvatore, welcome to stackoverflow. is italian the default language? the rule `RedirectMatch 301 /en/(.) /$1` will **redirect** `https://www.mywebsite.it/en/art/architecture/` to `https://www.mywebsite.it/art/architecture/`. how did your app decide which homepage the end user should see?

Comment: italioan is default. I'm using wordpress with the plugin polylang. this plugin will redirect the italian visitors to the italian language, everyone else to the english version. Thanks

Comment: hi salvatore, do you know the parameter that the plugin use to decide the language it should show?

Comment: with the plugin the language will be set from content . Thanks

Comment: uh, this is confusing. just to be sure, you want to make the language parameter (which used by the plugin to decide which language it show) invisible to end user while keeping the multilanguage support?